# Typescript sort by string property value

Tags: arrays, typescript, sorting

I have a list of object I want to sort by string property. Property values are **D1, D2 ... D10 ... DXX**. It's always **D** with **number**. When I use this code to sort the array by property, it doesn't sort it the way I expect to - ascending. I am using this piece of code to sort array.

```
this.list = v.sort((a, b) => a.property.localeCompare(b.property));
```

Result are sorted like this:

| Index | Property value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | D10 |
| 1 | D11 |
| 2 | D3 |
| 3 | D5 |
| ... | ... |

How do I achieve sorting it the right way? Example:

| Index | Property value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | D3 |
| 1 | D5 |
| 2 | D10 |
| 3 | D11 |
| ... | ... |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your properties are strings, therefore they are sorted [lexicographically](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/127644)

What I believe you want is to sort by the "numeric component of your string value". You therefore have to extract the number from the string to perform a numeric sort

```
extractNumber(stringValue: string) {
  // Assumes all strings have a single character 'D' prepended
  return Number(stringValue.slice(1))
}

this.list = v.sort((a, b) => extractNumber(a.property) - extractNumber(b.property));
```

Comment: Using `stringValue.slice(1)` would be faster than substring in this situation.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the answer to reflect that